# How are GCN doing semi-supervised learning?

Tags: papers, graph-neural-networks, semi-supervised-learning, spectral-clustering

In [Semi-Supervised Classification with Graph Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.02907), the authors say that GCN is an approach for *semi-supervised learning* (SSL).

But a GCN is making predictions using only the graph Laplacian. The single place where I find the labels is in its loss function.

$$\mathcal{L}=-\sum_{l \in \mathcal{Y}_{L}} \sum_{f=1}^{F} Y_{l f} \ln Z_{l f}$$

How does it make GCN a SSL approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the introduction, the authors write

> We consider the problem of classifying nodes (such as documents) in a graph (such as a citation network), where labels are only available for a small subset of nodes. This problem can be framed as graph-based semi-supervised learning, where **label information is smoothed over the graph via some form of explicit graph-based regularization** (Zhu et al., 2003; Zhou et al., 2004; Belkin et al., 2006; Weston et al., 2012), e.g. by using a **graph Laplacian regularization term** in the loss function:
> $$
> \mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{0}+\lambda \mathcal{L}_{\text {reg }}, \quad \text { with } \quad \mathcal{L}_{\text {reg }}=\sum_{i, j} \color{red}{A}_{i j}\left\|f\left(X_{i}\right)-f\left(X_{j}\right)\right\|^{2}=f(X)^{\top} \color{blue}{\Delta} f(X)
> $$
> Here, $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ denotes the supervised loss w.r.t. the labeled part of the graph, $f(\cdot)$ can be a neural network-like differentiable function, $\lambda$ is a weighing factor and $X$ is a matrix of node feature vectors $X_{i}$. $\color{blue}{\Delta}=D-\color{red}{A}$ denotes the unnormalized graph Laplacian of an undirected graph $\mathcal{G}=(\mathcal{V}, \mathcal{E})$ with $N$ nodes $v_{i} \in \mathcal{V}$, edges $\left(v_{i}, v_{j}\right) \in \mathcal{E}$, an adjacency matrix $\color{red}{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ (binary or weighted) and a degree matrix $D_{i i}=\sum_{j} \color{red}{A}_{i j} .$ The formulation of Eq. 1 relies on the **assumption that connected nodes in the graph are likely to share the same label**. This assumption, however, **might restrict modeling capacity, as graph edges need not necessarily encode node similarity, but could contain additional information**.

So, if you want to solve a node classification problem, where labels are available only for a small subset of the nodes, you can solve it by framing it with a specific loss function, $\mathcal{L}$, which is the sum of $L_0$ and a **regularisation term**, where

- $L_0$ is the term of the loss function that takes care of the nodes that have labels (i.e. it's computed as a function of the nodes that have labels), while
- $\mathcal{L}_{\text {reg }}$ is supposed to take care of the nodes without (and with) labels. Why? I don't know exactly, but I suspect this is due to the fact that it uses the information contained in $\color{red}{A}$ (the adjacency matrix) or $\color{blue}{\Delta}$ (the Laplacian).

However, this approach, as they claim, can be limiting, and the explanation is above (the last sentences **in bold** of the quoted excerpt).

To overcome this limitation, they decide to pass the adjacency matrix $\color{red}{A}$ to the neural network $f$, or, as they claim, to condition $f$ on $\color{red}{A}$. The idea is that, by doing this, the neural network $f$ will learn the graph structure. They write

> In this work, we encode the graph structure directly using a neural network model $f(X, \color{red}{A})$ and train on a supervised target $\mathcal{L}_{0}$ **for all nodes with labels**, thereby **avoiding explicit graph-based regularization in the loss function**. Conditioning $f(\cdot)$ on the adjacency matrix of the graph will allow the model to **distribute gradient information from the supervised loss $\mathcal{L}_{0}$** and will enable it to **learn representations of nodes both with and without labels**.

So, their graph neural network is defined as follows (equation 9)

$$
Z=f(X, \color{red}{A})=\operatorname{softmax}\left(\hat{\color{red}{A}} \operatorname{ReLU}\left(\hat{\color{red}{A}} X W^{(0)}\right) W^{(1)}\right),
$$
where $Z$ are the predictions (i.e. labels for the nodes $X$).

Their loss function is then defined only for $X$ that have labels

$$\mathcal{L}=-\sum_{l \in \mathcal{Y}_{L}} \sum_{f=1}^{F} Y_{l f} \ln Z_{l f},$$

where $\mathcal{Y}_{L}$ is the set of node indices that have labels. However, note that $Z_{l f}$ is still computed as a function of $\color{red}{A}$, which contains information about all nodes (labeled and unlabelled).

**To conclude**, their approach is a semi-supervised learning approach because they train the neural network with a training dataset, which is only partially labeled, to perform node classification. Their approach is different from previous approaches (which include a regularisation term to account for the part of the graph without labels) by defining the graph neural network as a function $f$ that also takes as an input $\color{red}{A}$, $f(X, \color{red}{A})$, which, supposedly, is what makes this approach work.

(**Disclaimer**: I've only quickly read a few other parts of the paper, and it had been a while since I extensively read something about graph neural networks.)